# Create textfile with all installed conda dependencies versions in Snakemake pipeline

Tags: yaml, conda, bioinformatics, snakemake

I would like to know if it's possible to create/echo a list of all installed conda packages/dependencies in a Snakemake pipeline. I'm currently using .yaml files which define the dependencies to install.

For example

medaka.yaml

```
name: medaka
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
dependencies:
  - medaka
```

Which downloads the latest version of Medaka.

Is there an easy way to print a list of all package versions used by my pipeline?
Like this

```
Program             Version
Medaka              1.1.3
FastQC              0.11.9
Trimmomatic         0.38
```

Comment: Do you mean across all rules and their corresponding environments? I don't think so... We implemented something like this for [seq2science](https://vanheeringen-lab.github.io/seq2science/content/gettingstarted.html#getting-an-explanation-of-what-seq2science-did), and required some custom code. (just some self-advertisement, seq2science works with any genome assembly, so also medaka, and does trimming, qc, alignment, etc. Take a look!)

Comment: Thanks Maarten :) Yes, across all rules and their corresponding environments. It isn't quite necessary but may help resolve problems later on when others are working with my pipeline.  I'll have a look at your pipeline.

Comment: p.s. you can also take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64043879/how-to-trace-back-exact-software-versions-used-to-generate-result-files-in-a-s
It's per rule though..

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the conda env export > {log} option and it seems to be working okay (It does specify all the other required dependencies which the package needs to download so it kinda clutters the textfile if I would append all the 'env exports' to one textfile.) I will have a look at the opened issue from @SebastianMüller in the upcoming weeks, maybe a more elegant solution will be implemented into Snakemake :).

Answer (score 0):

I would parse the output of `conda list` in order to print all versions of the conda environment:

```
rule condaTools:
    output: "tools.txt"
    shell: """
           conda list | grep -v "^#" | sed 's/ \+/\t/g' | cut -f1,2 > {output}
           """
```

If you have multiple environments, you can specify the name for each with `conda list -n <env_name>`